# Canvas drawImage method does not draw

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an issue with [drawImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImage.html) function. when I invoke

```
    var paint = ui.Paint();
    c.drawImage(backgroundImage, ui.Offset.zero, paint);
```

The image is drawn on emulator but on Huawei P20 it's not. When I run the app with

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

then the image is loaded but the UI is slow (I'm using [photo_view](https://github.com/renancaraujo/photo_view) to display the image and the dragging and zooming speed is unacceptable).

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: post full code to get help. This is quite hard like that

Comment: Image widget does work without that switch. I load asset resource. Regarding the code, please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53217074/5492496 I'm using this very same code. What is more, the background image is not loaded when I draw it on the canvas, when I return it directly in MapRenderer.renderMap then everything is fine.

Comment: As I described, everything works on emulator and on Huawei P20 with the flag. But does not without that flag so there must be some issue with rendering.